# Excel sumproduct accross multiple ranges and COUNT the results

Tags: excel, count, sum, excel-formula

I would like to count the number of occurances of a range of numbers between two dates and am having tremendous dificulty

On one Workbook we have a data showing the date that an event took place and the ID of the person who hosted the event.

We then want to tally up the totals on another.

To get the total number of events that took place on a date for a particular group of user IDs we have a workbook with two dates in column A and B and this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AB$3:$AB$71692>=A3)*('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AB$3:$AB$71692<=B3)*('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$71692>=548)*('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$71692>=554)
```

This gives the total number of events for this group of users between these two dates.

In a second column we want to know the total number of people from this group who have turned up to any events on this day. So essentially we want to COUNT the number unique of user IDs between 548 and 554 who have entered records between these two dates.

How would this be achieved?

Comment: could you add a screenshot of what your data look alike? this would be easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this "array formula"

`=SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH({548,549,550,551,552,553,554},IF(('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AB$3:$AB$71692>=A3)*('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AB$3:$AB$71692<=B3),'[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$71692),0))+0)`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

For larger ranges than `548 to 554`, e.g. `500 to 600` change to this version:

`=SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT("500:600")),IF(('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AB$3:$AB$71692>=A3)*('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AB$3:$AB$71692<=B3),'[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$71692),0))+0)`